# pulling SQL Data From Multiple Tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am having difficulty when trying to retrieve data from and SQL Query.

I am running the Querys using PHP on a HTML website.

The previous page has a button with :

```
href="edit_Job.php?edit=<?php echo $result->JobID;?>">Edit Job
```

This is using the JobID in my Jobs Table to pull the data to the next page Edit_job.php

Top of the next page I have a bit of PHP Code :

```
 if(isset($_GET['edit']))
    {
        $editid=$_GET['edit'];
    }
```

Whilst I am getting the data from the Jobs table I have other tables where I need to pull data.

Just as an overview I have three tables where i need the data to pull data from each table has a foreign key as described below.

```
Jobs 
=======
JobID 
JobTitle
Client 
SiteName

Sites
=======
SideID
Client
Site

Clients
=======
ClientID
SiteID
ClientName
```

- Clients Can have Multiple Jobs and Sites.
- Jobs Can have Multiple Sites.
- Sites Can Have Multiple Jobs but only one Client.

How would it be possible to retrieve data from these tables using PHP? I have been searching the internet I have tried inner joins, joins, select from where etc.

I can get results on PHPMYADMIN using

```sql
SELECT Jobs.Sitename, Sites.Site FROM Jobs INNER JOIN Sites ON Jobs.Sitename = Sites.site
```

but this is not specific information from EDIT

any Help would be appreciated

Comment: if you have the same client id or name in all those tables just relate to that to call any aspect for that user

Comment: I am trying that but I cannot seem to get anywhere with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are going to need some [many to many](http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/many-to-many-relationships/) tables to get the info you want. This will require a bit of a DB redesign.

In a many-to-many table, the table only contains two columns of IDs you need to pair together. Make tables like this:

```
Jobs_Sites
=======
JobID
SiteID    

Clients_Jobs
=======
ClientID
JobID
```

Here is a full example of a DB that would accomplish this.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Jobs` (
  `JobID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `JobTitle` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`JobID`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Sites` (
  `SiteID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SiteName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `ClientID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SiteID`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Clients` (
  `ClientID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ClientName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Jobs_Sites` (
  `JobID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SiteID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`JobID`, `SiteID`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Clients_Jobs` (
  `ClientID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `JobID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ClientID`, `JobID`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `Jobs` (`JobID`, `JobTitle`) VALUES
  (1, 'Big job'),
  (2, 'Small job'),
  (3, 'Cheap job'),
  (4, 'Difficult job');

INSERT INTO `Sites` (`SiteID`, `SiteName`, `ClientID`) VALUES
  (1, 'Park', 1),
  (2, 'City', 2),
  (3, 'Road', 1);

INSERT INTO `Clients` (`ClientID`, `ClientName`) VALUES
  (1, 'Bob'),
  (2, 'Hannah'),
  (3, 'Jimmy');

INSERT INTO `Jobs_Sites` (`JobID`, `SiteID`) VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 3),
  (2, 1),
  (3, 2),
  (3, 3),
  (4, 3);

INSERT INTO `Clients_Jobs` (`ClientID`, `JobID`) VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (2, 3),
  (3, 4),
  (3, 1);
```

Then you can do queries like this:

**Get Job info**

```sql
SELECT j.JobId,
       j.JobTitle,
       s.SiteID,
       s.SiteName,
       c.ClientId,
       c.ClientName
FROM Jobs j
     JOIN Jobs_Sites js ON j.JobID = js.JobID
     JOIN Sites s ON s.SiteID = js.SiteID
     JOIN Clients_Jobs cj ON cj.JobID = j.JobID
     JOIN Clients c ON c.ClientID = cj.ClientID
WHERE j.JobID = 1
```

Result

```
JobId   JobTitle    SiteID  SiteName    ClientId    ClientName
1       Big job     1       Park        1           Bob
1       Big job     2       City        1           Bob
1       Big job     3       Road        1           Bob
1       Big job     1       Park        3           Jimmy
1       Big job     2       City        3           Jimmy
1       Big job     3       Road        3           Jimmy
```

**Get Client info**

```sql
SELECT j.JobId,
       j.JobTitle,
       s.SiteID,
       s.SiteName,
       c.ClientId,
       c.ClientName
FROM Jobs j
     JOIN Jobs_Sites js ON j.JobID = js.JobID
     JOIN Sites s ON s.SiteID = js.SiteID
     JOIN Clients_Jobs cj ON cj.JobID = j.JobID
     JOIN Clients c ON c.ClientID = cj.ClientID
WHERE c.ClientID = 2
```

Result

```
JobId   JobTitle    SiteID  SiteName    ClientId    ClientName
3       Cheap job   2       City        2           Hannah
3       Cheap job   3       Road        2           Hannah
```

If this isn't exactly what you want this should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: thank you for your input, it was muchley appreciated I was able to get it working over the Christmas break :)

Comment: Wonderful. If my answer helped you, could you upvote and accept as the answer? Thank you.